# GDI+ LockBits()/UnLockBits() Exception

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

My program is written in C# and manipulates with bitmaps on low level. Everything works fine, but sometimes (very rarely, but stable) exception "Generic GDI+ exception" occurs, and it is very hard to reproduce such situations.

Exception happens on functions LockBits() and UnLockBits(). It contains error code "-2147467259". On the language of GDI+ it would be method GdipBitmapLockBits and return code 7 or 1.

What kind of reasons may cause such situations?

Any answers greatly appreciate.

Comment: Could you paste a code snippet showing your code?

Comment: Something wrong with the underlying storage for the bitmap data.  Could be locked (avoid threading), could be a disposed memory stream, could be out of virtual memory.

Comment: Do you have permissions to read/write the bitmap?

Comment: @HansPassant I tried to reproduce exception, filling the memory with lots of bytes and looping lockbits() and unlockbits() for thousands times, no exceptions occured. It looks like this methods doesn't use memory at all. Disposing bitmap streams causes InvalidOperationException, not generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigated this problem and it seems that it might be connected with threads.
I don't know for sure what really causes that issues and have no proofs, but after setting up locks throughout the code the problem seems to have gone.

Answer (score 4):

GDI+ objects are not thread-safe, and using them from multiple threads without synchronization could certainly cause crashes. For completeness, I want to add that it's possible to free the memory backing a GDI+ bitmap before freeing the bitmap, and in such cases you'd get an invalid access when attempting to use the bitmap. This can only happen if you allocate the pixel data yourself and use a constructor that takes a pointer to the data, such as this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx