# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when converting image to array to image

Tags: c#, arrays, image, bitmap, gdi+

I have here existing code that I need to fix because for unknown reasons, our .dll files were probably replaced.

I am having problems on using the image for OCR (Python Tesseract). Below is the how the code works:

```
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
byte[] imgArray = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
```

I am passing the image to make it into byte[] then pass it on the API. Then the API converts the array to image:

```
public Bitmap ConvertToImage(byte[] arr)
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
  {
      return new Bitmap(ms);
  }

}
```

As an example, when I use `Bitmap img2 = ConvertToImage(imgArray);`, it gives me the error

[image: innerException+stacktrace+message]

I only get the GDI error when I try to use the image from the converted array. But when I use the straight image file (open file dialog) there seems to be no problem.
I can't really change the code, so can anyone suggest a solution? Or what's the problem when I used the array to image file?

Comment: [Is this related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed)

Comment: @John uhm, I think not. I am not saving anything, that's why I cannot find a solution for this. I am merely using the converted image, and it throws me an error.

Comment: The only other related question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996484/gdi-lockbits-unlockbits-exception/13193740) - are you doing anything with threading?